# get string with foreach in datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, foreach, getstring

I create a function with the aim to show the concatenated string to the DataGrid that I made ​​such:

> file1.exe, file2.docx, file3.mp3

how to display that way? I have tried it but messagebox displays an empty string.

This is the code :

```
public void View()
{
    string namaFile = string.Empty;
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DGVDekripsi.Rows)
    {
       string NameFile = (string)row.Cells[0].Value;
       namaFile += NameFile + ",";
    }
    MessageBox.Show(namaFile);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your your first cells of all rows are not empty? Did you debug your code? Your code seems fine to me.

Comment: @Soner I make mistakes, I mean datagridview was not that I use the code. Yes. it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I could see your code not working is if you had no rows in your `DataGridView`, so there was nothing to iterate over. Even if you had several rows and they all had empty names, you'd at least get a string with several commas in it.

Also, here's a slightly shorter way to get your list of names, using LINQ:

```
var allNames = string.Join(",",
               DGVDekripsi.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(x => x.Field<string>(0)));
```

Comment: Thanks, this using 'Join'. I will also try it.